# Xamarin.Forms Android app wont open in vs 2017

Tags: xamarin.forms

After creating an Xamarin.forms app, the android app wont open

[image]

It just hangs on this status and after a while becomes ready, but the app does not open in emulator

Comment: Have you tried to cancel the build and restart deploying the app? I've had that problem a few times, but restarting the build or even visual studio 'fixed' it..

Comment: Nothing works. Restarting vs doesn't help

Comment: Is this question closed?

Comment: Yep! I got it to work! I had to wait for 10 mins for the app to be deployed!